# Showing $f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} f(z_0+Re^{i\theta}) \ d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Suppose that $f$ is analytic on and inside the circle $|z-z_0|=R$.
Show carefully that $f(z_0)$ is equal to the average of $f$ on
${|z-z_0|=R}$,  i.e. show that
$$f(z_0)={1 \over {2 \pi}} \int_0^{2 \pi} f(z_0+Re^{i\theta}) \
d\theta$$

We are trying to use the cauchy integral formula to solve for it. We have it set up as $f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{Re^{i\theta}}dz$

This is where we get suck. Need some direction for where to go!!!

Comment: $z-z_0 \neq R$. It's $z-z_0 = Re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I will make that change right away, thanks! We are still confused though :(

Comment: If you parametrise the circle $\kappa(\theta) = z_0 + Re^{i\theta}$, what is the resulting integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If we let $z=z_0+Re^{i\theta}$, then
$$
\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(z_0+Re^{i\theta})\,\mathrm{d}\theta
=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint f(z)\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-z_0}
$$
where the path is the circle of radius $R$ counterclockwise around $z_0$.

Next, look for the singularities of the integrand then use [Cauchy's Integral Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).

Comment: But we are given that it is analytic on and inside the circle, so there won't be any singularities right?

Comment: The $f(z)$ is not the integrand...

Comment: ooooooooooooooo, we figured it out! Thank you for all the help!

Comment: @Blaris: :-) Any time!

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at this is that $f$ being analytic means it is holomorphic,  and thus satisfies the cauchy reimann equations.

Now consider laplace's equation in $\mathbb { R }^2$:

$-\Delta f=0\Rightarrow -(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac {\partial^2}{\partial y^2})f=0\Rightarrow - (\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac {\partial}{\partial y})(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac {\partial}{\partial y})f=0$ taking each coefficient gives us the cauchy riemann equations. Thus $f$ satisfies the laplace equation and thus is harmonic.

A harmonic function has the property that the function evealuated at a point is equivalent to the mean integral of the function over the boundary of a sphere centred at such point.

Thus $ f(z_0 )=\frac {1}{2\pi R}\int_0 ^{2\pi}f(z_0+Re^{i\theta})d\theta$

Note that this is the integral over the boundary of the circle radius $R$ centred at $z_0$.